# uncaught soapfault exception

Tags: php, soap, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to work with php-ews at the moment, however having some sort of issue with soap which i have no idea about, below is the error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [VersionMismatch] Wrong Version in C:\wamp\www\intranet\dashboard\php-ews\ExchangeWebServices.php:230 Stack trace: #0 C:\wamp\www\intranet\dashboard\php-ews\ExchangeWebServices.php(230): SoapClient->__call('FindItem', Array) #1 C:\wamp\www\intranet\dashboard\php-ews\ExchangeWebServices.php(230): NTLMSoapClient_Exchange->FindItem(Object(EWSType_FindItemType)) #2 C:\wamp\www\intranet\dashboard\mailtest.php(56): ExchangeWebServices->FindItem(Object(EWSType_FindItemType)) #3 {main} thrown in C:\wamp\www\intranet\dashboard\php-ews\ExchangeWebServices.php on line 230
```

line 230 of that file is as so

```
public function FindItem($request) {
        return $this->initializeSoapClient()->{__FUNCTION__}($request);
    }
```

if anyone has any ideas, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
public function FindItem($request) {
    try {
    return $this->initializeSoapClient()->{__FUNCTION__}($request);
    }
catch(SoapFault $ex) {
        print $ex->getMessage();
        print $ex->getTraceAsString()
    }
 }
```

and take a look at [PHP SOAPClient](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php)

Comment: unfortunatly that returns the following #0 C:\wamp\www\intranet\dashboard\php-ews\ExchangeWebServices.php(235): SoapClient->__call('FindItem', Array) #1 C:\wamp\www\intranet\dashboard\php-ews\ExchangeWebServices.php(235): NTLMSoapClient_Exchange->FindItem(Object(EWSType_FindItemType)) #2 C:\wamp\www\intranet\dashboard\mailtest.php(56): ExchangeWebServices->FindItem(Object(EWSType_FindItemType)) #3 {main}

Comment: please add print $ex->getMessage(); is this the total error message

Comment: new output is Wrong Version#0 C:\wamp\www\intranet\dashboard\php-ews\ExchangeWebServices.php(234): SoapClient->__call('FindItem', Array) #1 C:\wamp\www\intranet\dashboard\php-ews\ExchangeWebServices.php(234): NTLMSoapClient_Exchange->FindItem(Object(EWSType_FindItemType)) #2 C:\wamp\www\intranet\dashboard\mailtest.php(56): ExchangeWebServices->FindItem(Object(EWSType_FindItemType)) #3 {main}